# Services Twilio Rest Exception source phone number is not yet verified

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

Exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The source phone number provided, +91XXXXXXXXXX, is not yet verified for your account. You may only make calls from phone numbers that you've verified or purchased from Twilio.'

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using a trial version of twilio. for that you have to register your mobile number first after login. then you will be able to send text on that registered mobile number only.

[click on this link after login, you have to register that number there](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/verified)

```
require '/path/to/your/Twilio/autoload.php';   

use Twilio\Rest\Client;   

$sid = 'your_sid_here';
$token = 'your_token_here';
$client = new Client($sid, $token);
$from="get the sender number";
$to="registered mobile number";

$send=$client->messages->create(

    $to,
    array(

        'from' => $from,

        'body' => "your message here"
    )
);
if($send)
{
    print_r($send);

}
else
{
    echo "message not sent";
}
```

try to use this API with valid credentials.

Comment: I have registered my number and have verified it using a call method from Twilio. But still I am getting the error.

Comment: then it could be a wrong token or sid or from number.